# Best approach to read data from tera terminal into Java

Tags: java

Details:  Read data from EEPROM -> output to tera term -> save off log file -> parse through it with java program.

What I have: All EEPROM reads are good.  I then take the hex value I read and using sprintf (in Atmel Studio) turn each byte into its 2 respective ASCII codes.  Then I send this out to tera term.  Output is as follows:

```
 00=00=00=c5=03=76=00=01=00=05=00=cf=00=01=fa=ef=
 00=00=00=c6=00=44=00=01=00=05=00=cf=00=00=fe=21=
 00=00=00=c8=02=41=00=01=00=05=00=d0=00=01=fc=20=
```

etc...

I can then parse through it in this manner using a java program I slightly modified:

```
Seconds: 0x15150380 Milliseconds: 0x0062 Cycle Count: 0x0001 Assert Code: 0x0005 Parameter: 0x00d1 Data Value: 0x006c Checksum: 0xfa5e
```

(first 4 bytes are seconds, next 2 are milliseconds, etc.)

Next:
For starters I would just like to read each line (1 log) into a byte array so I can verify packet with checksum at end, etc.

My questions:

1) How to read that type of output to an array

2) Would it be better/easier to output data to teraterminal in a different manner?  And if so any pointers are appreciated.

Completely new to Java so trying to piece throught this...
Thanks for the help.